# The meaning of the word "Right?" in response to a statement

Tags: meaning-in-context

I think I heard someone make a statement and then the other person responded with "Right?" For example, the person might have said its so hot today and the other person responded with Right?". My first question is did I hear that right? I mean is that correct english. And if it is, then what does it "Right?" mean. Does it mean that the person agrees with the statement?

Answer (score 2):

"Right?" in this manner essentially is short for "Isn't that one of those evident truths that anyone should find themselves able to agree on?".

A more spelled out version of this kind of phrase approximating a rhetorical question would be "don't I know?".

A non-question version would be something like "you took the words right out of my mouth".